# Sign in Azure AD users through Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am building custom B2C policy to set up sign in of Azure AD users through Azure B2C. This is the link that I am following - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

I am unclear on these

1. Which starter pack should be used when Azure AD is identity provider? I am using socialandlocalaccounts pack - is that correct?
2. after I follow instructions in MS link above, I get a Azure AD screen to log in. I enter AD credentials, log in is successful, I can see that a user entry is created in Azure B2C Tenant->Users. So user info from Azure AD is now being created as a local user in B2C. Is this expected? I cannot find any documentation that describes this behavior.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Hi MSLearner,  Socialandlocalaccounts  starter pack is the best choice if you want to allow users to sign in with Azure AD Credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In custom policies, social = federation which is what you are doing with Azure AD.

Yes, federated users are created in Azure AD as "shadow accounts". They are not local users. These users cannot log in to B2C directly.

You will see in the User blade that they are a "different" type of user.

If you look at the user attributes:

```
"identities": [
  {
    "signInType": "userName",
    "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
    "issuerAssignedId": "johnsmith"
  },
  {
    "signInType": "emailAddress",
    "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
    "issuerAssignedId": "jsmith@yahoo.com"
  },
  {
    "signInType": "federated",
    "issuer": "facebook.com",
    "issuerAssignedId": "5eecb0cd"
  }
]
```